# Looping through MySQL when you have multiple languages - non-English alphabets garbled

Tags: php, mysql, encoding

I'm looping through a database table -

```
$preg_pattern = '/- (\d|\D)/';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($loop))
{
    if(!preg_match($preg_pattern,$row['post_title']) OR is_null($row['post_content'])):
        echo '<h3>' . $row['post_title'] . '</h3>';
        echo '<p>' . $row['post_content'] . '</p>';
        echo '<br/>';
    endif;
}
```

that has both English, Russian, Chinese and Indian alphabets.  When I echo the above, I get: http://screencast.com/t/Alv8CMjMn

I can detect what language each using $row['post_name'], for example, if it has 'zh' in it then I know it's Chinese.

How can I make sure it's outputting as readable in the right language?  When I view the language rows in phpmyadmin, they are fine: http://screencast.com/t/fzjBdcAfJ

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: My database collation for those fields is utf8_general_ci

Comment: Try `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` at the top of your page and `mysql_set_charset('utf8');` also consider changing from `mysql_*` functions as they are depreciated.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the data in phpAdmin? Do you see the characters right there?

Comment: That worked Matt, thanks!